# Canextract=true(abcpdf8) is not setting page extraction as allowed

Tags: .net

I am trying to set page extraction as allowed through code . I am using abcpdf8 canextract=true but even after doing it, it's not working. I have set doctype as 2 even after that it's not working.

Fix the issues that I am facing . Please help me with this .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.